# Job for apache2.service fails

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache

Running `sudo service apache2 start` brings up the following error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running `journalctl -xe` displays the following:

```
Jul 12 17:09:31 home-server sudo[641011]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 12 17:10:24 home-server sudo[641703]:     ghar : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/etc/apache2 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 start
Jul 12 17:10:24 home-server sudo[641703]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by ghar(uid=1000)
Jul 12 17:10:26 home-server sudo[641703]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 12 17:10:30 home-server sudo[641719]:     ghar : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/etc/apache2 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 status
Jul 12 17:10:30 home-server sudo[641719]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by ghar(uid=1000)
Jul 12 17:12:14 home-server sudo[641719]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 12 17:12:43 home-server sudo[641737]:     ghar : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/etc/apache2 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service apache2 start
Jul 12 17:12:43 home-server sudo[641737]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by ghar(uid=1000)
Jul 12 17:12:44 home-server sudo[641737]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Running `systemctl status apache2.service` displays the following:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-07-12 17:12:44 +04; 24min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 641745 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 25ms
```

Here's what all I've tried:

1. Purging and reinstalling apache2 multiple times to no avail.
2. Checking if any services are currently using port 80/8080. Tried disabling pi-hole. Can't disable tailscale because that's the way I'm sshing into the server.